# Regex for restricting special char and allow only dot and &

Tags: regex

I am not getting any regex which should restrict user to enter special char.

In my condition I want to restrict all the special char. except . and & means user can enter . and &. apart from this 2 special char user should be able to not enter any special char.

Some one please help me.

Comment: What is a special char for you? Are `çéà` special?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[.&a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

should be enough for you.

Comment: That's right or not depending of what a special character is.

Comment: As you have given the regex, If I want to allow some other spcl char I can add that as well, isn't it

Comment: @Rocky sure you can add whichever character you want to allow inside `[]` , suppose you want to allow `%` then your regex will change like this : `^[.&a-zA-Z0-9%]+$`